# How can I programmatically generate keyDown events in Silverlight?

Tags: events, silverlight-3.0, textbox, keydown, raise

I have 2 textBoxes. First is visible the second is not.
When keyDown event fires on first textBox I want to fire the same event on 2nd textBox, so it would react same as if user was typing in 2nd textBox.

How can I do that?

---

EDIT:
I know you can do this in Windows.Forums and I was hoping that it can be done here too.

My goal is to have 2 textBoxes with different texts in it, but when user types something in 1st textBox same text should appear in 2nd textBox.

Example:
Text in first textBox:

```
<home>
 <number>75</number>
 <client>John</client>
</home>
```

Text in second textBox

```
<home>
 <number id="123">75</number>
 <client id="345">John</client>
</home>
```

Now user types some new text in first textBox like:

```
<home>
 <number>150</number>
 <client>John</client>
</home>
```

And now this new text should appear in 2nd textBox like:

```
<home>
 <number id="123">150</number>
 <client id="345">John</client>
</home>
```

And this is only an example for changing values. User can also add new elements, delete them, change order and so on.

I have tried with mapping KeyEventArgs but I loose control for non-standard keys like: "šđžćč<>"

Comment: The answer to the question as is stands is; you can't.   Why would you want to do that anyway?  Perhaps there is another way to acheive you real goal.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mimic the keyboard in the way you seem to want.

Comment: Ok, I edited my first post so its more clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is add an eventhandler to the textboxes and in that eventhandler update the second textbox value based on the first one and vice versa.

```
TextChanged
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged(v=VS.95).aspx

```
private void FirstTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SecondTextBox.Text = FirstTextBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: Nope, don't you see that texts are not identical. 1st text doesn't have attributes and the 2nd does. Copying text like this won't work in my case.

Comment: Ok but you'd still had to use eventhandlers i think. Maybe some regular expression magic within the eventhandler? replace only text between the given tags <name *></name> ?

Comment: Tags can change too, and order of them so it is not so simple as it looks like. That is why I wish to do key sync between both textBoxes. It is like the only way to do it.